# Accessing a list by index in a for loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I am trying to access specific elements in a list within a for loop. However, when a repeated item appears the index is given for the first instance.

For example:

```py
my_list = [1,2,2,3,2,1]
for i in my_list:
     return my_list.index(i)
```

When the for loop has reached the last element it will return 0 rather than my desired output of 5.
How do I get the index of the specific 'i' the loop is using?

Comment: You want `my_list[i]`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing the index in 'for' loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-for-loops)

Answer (score 0):

Let say you want to find:

```
index_of = 2
```

Now lets get index of that element:

```
 [i for i in range(len([1,2,2,3,2,1])) if [1,2,2,3,2,1][i] ==index_of]
```

gives all index of that element:

```
[1, 2, 4]
```

Comment: Why?  There's `list.index()` which is better, faster and more compact.

Comment: list.index() returns the first index

Comment: @OlvinRoght I didn't get you

Answer (score 0):

Use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for index, value in enumerate(my_list):
    print('Value {} at position {}'.format(value, index))
```